# Python not reading a function

Tags: python, multithreading

```
from dist import *
import csv
import Jetson.GPIO as GPIO
import threading

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

led_pin = 7
botao_pin = 15
luz=False
antes=True
contador = 0
counter = 0
GPIO.setup(botao_pin, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(led_pin, GPIO.OUT)


ax=0
ay=0
az=0
wx=0
wy=0
wz=0
data=0

def leracc():
        global ax,ay,az,wx,wy,wz
        ax,ay,az,wx,wy,wz = ASM330_conv()
        return ax,ay,az,wx,wy,wz


def lerSD():
        global data
        data  = SD_start()
        return data


print('Primeiro', az)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=leracc)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=lerSD)


header = ["gX","gY","gZ","Centimetros","Latitude","Longitude","Altitude","Velocidade","ErroLat","ErroLon","ErroAlt","Horas"]
headeracc = ["AccelX","AccelY","AccelZ"]

while 1:
            try:
                    t1.start()
                    t2.start()
                    
                    print('Segundo', az)

                    estado=GPIO.input(botao_pin)
                    if (antes==True and estado==False):         #desliga e liga o led após clique
                        luz=not(luz)
                    GPIO.output(led_pin, luz)
                    antes=estado

            except:
                    continue

            dados = [wx,wy,wz,data]             #armazena valores do giroscópio, sensor de distância e GPS
            dataacc = [ax,ay,az]                #armazena valores do acelerometro

            if(luz==True):
                with open ('/home/built/Desktop/Projetos/final/dados.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
                        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                        while(contador < 1):            #para escrever o cabecalho
                           writer.writerow(header)
                           contador = contador + 1

                        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                        writer.writerow(dados)          #escreve dados em dados.csv
                        csvFile.close()


                with open ('/home/built/Desktop/Projetos/final/acc.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
                        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                        while(counter < 1):
                           writer.writerow(headeracc)
                           counter = counter + 1

                        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                        writer.writerow(dataacc)                #escreve dataacc em acc.csv
                        csvFile.close()
```

So hi everyone. I want to read data from an accelerometer and a distance sensor and place these data in a csv file. I already managed to do it, but I wanted to implement threads to it.The function `ASM330_conv()`is what gives the accelerometer values, same as `SD_start()`for the distance sensor. Although, the `print('Primeiro', az)`is just to check if all is going well and it's printing 0, as it should. But in the `print('Segundo', az)` it still prints 0, so I don't know if the thread is not running, or there is any variables problem, I don't know. Any help?

Comment: Threads can be tricky, can you try printing `az` in the `leracc()` method? What's probably happening is that the thread doesn't actually run until after the print statement (even thought `start()` is called before `print()`).

Comment: Also consider working with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it helps a lot, specially for threading.